# how do we show whether it is uniformly equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

The sequence of functions $f_n(x):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined by:

$$f_n(x) = n+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sin({e^n}{x})$$

Is it uniformly equicontinuous or not?
I got stuck when I tried to use definition to prove its equicontinuity, neither can I prove it is not. Can any one help me out?
I tried to compute $$\mid{f_n(x)-f_n(y)}\mid=2\mid\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cos()\sin(\frac{{e^n}{(x-y)}}{2})\mid$$
But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Can you show your work?

Comment: their derivatives are unbounded as $n$ goes to infinity, but it does not directly mean they can't be equicontinuous, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can advance as

$$ |f_n(x)-f_n(y)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|\sin(e^n x)- \sin(e^n y)  | \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|e^n x - e^n y | = \frac{e^n}{\sqrt{n}}| x -  y | < \epsilon $$

$$ \implies |x-y|< \frac{\sqrt{n}}{e^n} \epsilon \implies |x-y| < \epsilon=\delta $$

since $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{e^n} <1,\, \forall n\geq 1$. I assume that know the definitions of equicontinuity and uniform continuity .

Comment: Okay, good point; my comments above were mistaken (deleting them).